# Apache redirecting to folder?

Tags: php, apache, hyperlink, directory, href

Hi my fellow developers :D

I´m working on a website.

There seems to be a problem with my blog link.
I´m using `<a href="blog">Blog</a>, <a href="about">About</a>` etc.

And that worked all the time and still does for every php file, except the "blog.php"
(I´ve set to ignore the php extension in the .htaccess file).

But it tries to go to: "beta.mywebsite.com/blog/" instead of: "beta.mywebsite.com/blog" like before.
When I try to go to the blog, it throws a 500 http status.

Edit:
The php file itself, seems to work, when I´ve disabled the .php "extension" and had a look at the blog page.

My .htaccess file:

```
# login for beta!
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Beta Access | Login Required"
Require user me

# php_flag display_errors on
# php_value error_reporting E_ALL

# Run Php without filename extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

# set index page
# DirectoryIndex index.php

# disable indexing, dont prompt files to download
Options -Indexes 
IndexOptions -FancyIndexing
IndexIgnore *.zip *.css *.php *.html *.js *.ktr *.txt

# enable CORS for php files
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(google.com|staging.google.com|development.google.com|googleads.g.doubleclick.net|mywebsite.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin

<Files "register.php">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        # Allow from localhost
        # Allow from 127.0.0.1
        # Allow from xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
</Files>

<Files "snd_reg.php">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        # Allow from localhost
        # Allow from 127.0.0.1
        # Allow from xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
</Files>

<Files "results.php">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        # Allow from localhost
        # Allow from 127.0.0.1
        # Allow from xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
</Files>

<Files "login.php">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        # Allow from localhost
        # Allow from 127.0.0.1
        # Allow from xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
</Files>

<Files "faq.php">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        # Allow from localhost
        # Allow from 127.0.0.1
        # Allow from xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
</Files>

<Files "up.php">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        # Allow from localhost
        # Allow from 127.0.0.1
        # Allow from xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
</Files>

<Files "lost.php">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        # Allow from localhost
        # Allow from 127.0.0.1
        # Allow from xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
</Files>


# allow post comment
<Files "post_comment.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>


# replace with http://www.beta.mywebsite.com/error.php?error=xxx

ErrorDocument 400 http://beta.mywebsite.com/error?error=400
ErrorDocument 401 http://beta.mywebsite.com/error?error=401
ErrorDocument 403 http://beta.mywebsite.com/error?error=403
ErrorDocument 404 http://beta.mywebsite.com/error?error=404
ErrorDocument 500 http://beta.mywebsite.com/error?error=500
ErrorDocument 503 http://beta.mywebsite.com/error?error=503
```

Has anyone got an idea?
Regards,

Comment: Well then it would be most likely the error is in the .htaccess file. Can you show us that

Comment: add a conditional slash in your rewrite, `/?` (before `$`)

Comment: added my htaccess, the strange thing is, that it was working before and every other still works.

Comment: when Im using "blog.php" as a link, it works, but the other link without the .php extension work aswell?